# Upload file out of the public_html

Tags: php, file-upload

I'd like to upload file out of the *public_html* directory, because of security reasons, but I can't do this, because it gives me this error message:

> **Warning:** move_uploaded_file() [[function.move-uploaded-file]](http://www.acslibertygroup.com/beta/admin/function.move-uploaded-file): Unable to access /opt/share/www/a/domainname/safety-download/file/20120517215405-2012-05-16--1-27-51.png in **/opt/share/www/a/domainname/public_html/beta/admin/dokumentum.php** on line **29**

I don't want to use MySQL - BLOB file upload, because I don't have enough space in my MySQL server to upload over 3000 files, with more than 5 MB file size, but I'd like to deny the users from accessing these files, because they contain personal details.

Thanks for your answers,
Barnabas

Comment: Change the permissions on the directory. Or, if you can't, try to find a directory where you can. It looks like the web server just doesn't have write permissions there.

Comment: I've tried it on CHMODE 777 on file, and folder also, but it fails always

Comment: Don't know it that was just a typeo here, but its `CHMOD` not `CHMODE` :)

Comment: Seems like a better question for serverfault than here.

Comment: I've spoken with my hoster, and he told me, that i couldn't set these privilages, and i have to send a mail for him, to do this... Sorry for your time!

Comment: I'd like to write CHMOD before, sorry. (but that's not typeo, just typo :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you have the rights to write in that folder ?

dirty fix

```
chmod a+w /opt/share/www/a/domainname/safety-download/file/
```

Or you can give the rights to apache to write in this folder. By changing the group of the folder to be the one of apache

And also make sure you call move_uploaded_file in the right order `$src, $dest`:

Comment: I've tried it, but it gives me ERROR 500, when i refreshed the site

move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileinputnev]["tmp_name"],"/opt/share/www/a/domainname/safety-download/".$fileinputnev."/".$ido.'-'.hircimtourl2($_FILES[$fileinputnev]["name"]));

Comment: That's gon' be good, but i need to talk with the server administrator, to do that :)